# Rewrite rule on htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I was trying to rewrite rule in htacces if url like https://mywebsite.com then do not rewrite to path app/ 
but if url like this https://mywebsite.com/whatever/ then that's only time to execute the rewrite rule app/

I want to execute only the rewrite app/ if the url has parameter or whatever has sub name.

here my sample htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Header set Referrer-Policy "origin"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below currently you are testing with `(.*)` zero and unlimited times which is taking `/` in group as well.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Header set Referrer-Policy "origin"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule !^$ app%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Well it is working [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=d2395dee-f49c-547c-b520-553bd0aaf866) am I missing something?

Comment: Yes its working if they have parameter or subname. When i try this https://mywebsite.com/ without parameter it did not read the index on root.